# Default password for geoserver 2.1.4 not working

Tags: geoserver

I have installed geoserver 2.1.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 i have jetty running on port 90.

I get to the login screen. I introduce user: admin password: geoserver and i am getting that user or passowrd are not correct!!

It is supposed that those are default user and pass. Can i change it on a file or something?

Maybe geoserver is not properly installed?

Regards,

Comment: There are two usernames and passwords for the master find security/masterpw.info http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/passwd.html

Comment: Thanks! That helped, you can add an aswer so i can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is also possible to **set a master password for GeoServer**. This password serves two purposes:

Protect access to the keystore
Protect access to the GeoServer Root account
By default, the master password is generated and stored in a file named security/masterpw.info using plain text. When upgrading from an existing GeoServer data directory (versions 2.1.x and lower), the algorithm attempts to figure out the password of a user with the role ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR. If such a password is found and the password length is 8 characters at minimum, GeoServer uses this password as master password. Again, the name of the chosen user is found in security/masterpw.info.

Warning The file security/masterpw.info **is a security risk**. The administrator should read this file and verify the master password by logging on GeoServer as the root user. On success, this file should be removed.

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/passwd.html